# Is a pointer an example of polymorphism?

Tags: pointers, memory, polymorphism, ram

Given that a pointer is a memory address in RAM that points to or identifies another memory address in RAM and polymorphism is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types or the use of a single symbol to represent multiple different types. It seems like you could argue that RAM is an interface that's uses a single symbol (memory address in this case) to represent multiple different types (other memory addresses in RAM that point to any type of data stored at that memory address). Is this a fair conclusion to draw?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a zoology textbook which said that the entities located at the following coordinates: `(x1, y1), ... (xn, yn)` are mammals, and defined mammals this way. Would you view this as legitimate? It is the opposite of "polymorphism".